# Is my .valid? is blocking my notice alerts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Issue:** My notices for my specific controller are not appearing.

It isn't the layout because it works elsewhere with other controllers using it.

**Here is the Create method:**

```
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
    @seller = @listing.user

    ....  
    ....
    ....

        if @order.valid?
          begin
            #stripe_charge_code_is_here

          rescue #stripe_error
             #code
          end
          if #code
             #flash[:error]
             #redirect_to
          else


        # respond_to do |format|
          if @order.save
            @order.update_column(:order_status, 1)
            # format.html { redirect_to order_confirmation_order_path(@order.order_token), notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
            # format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
            flash[:notice] = "successful notice here."
            redirect_to order_confirmation_order_path(@order.order_token)
            else
              # format.html { render :new }
              # format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
              flash[:alert] = "failed notice here.  View directions."
              redirect_to @order
            end
          end
        end
      end
```

Whether I use `flash[]` or `respond_to`, no flash message appears for both a successful order or failed order.  I left both on the code above, the `respond_to` is commented out

I mostly want a message for failed orders because one of the form entries for the order has a validation with a message and it's important for it to show so customers know what is wrong with their entry.  When failed, I get this in the **CMD:**

```
No template found for OrdersController#create, rendering head :no_content
```

Now, the only difference in this controller compared to others that use the same layout, is this create method has a .`valid?`

I am assuming this is what is stopping the notice from appearing.

How can I have it so the flash message(s) show for both successful creates and failed?

Comment: Have you tried `redirect_to @order, alert: "message here"` ? Also what the point of `begin` ?

Comment: That didn't work, i really think its the `valid?` - there's gotta be a way around this.  I've tried just about everything i can google.  `begin` works kind of like a validator.  If the charge isn't successful, it won't save, and if it's not `valid`, it won't charge.  at least that's my logic.  I've seen similar code for charging on here so I adopted it

Comment: Add some debugging to it.  Try adding some puts messages after the valid and save statements to make sure you're getting that far.

Answer (score 0):

You have no `else` block for the `if @order.valid?` condition. If the record is not valid, the method ends immediately and it tried to render the template with the same name as the controller action (`OrdersController#create`) which doesn't exist.

Rather you can try this:

```
    if @order.valid? && @order.save
      flash[:notice] = "successful notice here."
      redirect_to order_confirmation_order_path(@order.order_token)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "failed notice here.  View directions."
      redirect_to @order
    end
```

The `@order.update_column(:order_status, 1)` logic should probably be moved to the model later (in a `before_save` or something, so it doesn't issue an additional database call).

After you call `valid?` or `save`, you can get the validation errors from the model layer using `.errors.full_messages` (maybe you can show these in the error notice).

Comment: I updated the OP and put more code into the create code.  There technically is an `else` but it's for the errors.  But other than that, the `@order.valid? && @order.save` didn't do the trick.

Comment: I did try doing `if @order.valid? == false
          flash[:notice] = "Tweet link successfully updated."
        elsif @order.valid?` but still not appearing anything

Comment: @uno i still see no else for the `valid?`. Fix your indentation it may be more clear

Comment: I added an elsif invalid? and it's showing the error message i created for that but now not saving order.

Comment: @uno please try and approach this a little more systematically ... update the question with your new attempts, and show exactly what the new errors are. If it's not saving the order, then you can call `valid?` and `.errors.full_messages` to see the error. If you are having a hard time following the flow of your code, a debugger such as `pry` will be very useful.

Comment: i think i figured it out.  ill post an answer after more testing

Comment: Actually didn't get it to work how i wanted.  What i am doing instead is created a front-end validation so people know with a message if the input isn't valid right away --- as well as using the backend validation so nothing can sneak by